# Return objects from mongo inserted at similar time

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to group together documents that have been inserted into a collection by a user with a similar timeframe. I'm looking for documentation or a snippet to push me in the right direction on this pseudo code;

```
User submits a number of documents (over the course of five minutes) into a collection.
Documents are grouped together with similar timeframe.
User is returned a list of objects that were inserted within a timeframe (eg. 1hr).
```

Edit for clarity:

The publish function to the database with a timestamp is working and I can see documents stored in my collection correctly below;

```
{ "text" : "beef", "createdBy" : "X9Px6qKRjiB53ANST", "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-02-03T00:47:21.976Z"), "_id" : "sJhwcLCRS4CG6yfTe" }
{ "text" : "beef", "createdBy" : "X9Px6qKRjiB53ANST", "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-02-03T00:47:41.265Z"), "_id" : "NGBwiWZRsDBbNerSy" }
{ "text" : "Chicken", "createdBy" : "X9Px6qKRjiB53ANST", "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-02-03T02:47:21.163Z"), "_id" : "R2FYAjZamTWTy9RTW" }
{ "text" : "Chicken", "createdBy" : "X9Px6qKRjiB53ANST", "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-02-03T04:42:02.895Z"), "_id" : "F7u2EfBEmYLBaFgze" }
```

How do I group together the documents submitted within the same hour (eg both 'beef' documents and return that to the user? I have a basic return function that returns all entries but I can't find much information on grouping the data by the hour.

```
Meteor.publish('theFoods', function(){
    var currentUser = this.userId;

    return Foods.find({
        createdBy: currentUser
    })
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ajduke How do I group together the documents submitted within the same hour (eg both 'beef' documents and return that to the user?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you indicate exactly what output you want. I'm assuming you are looking for a helper which groups by hour so you can display that information to the user.

Comment: @DavidWeldon that is exactly what I need. I am currently return results and sorting them by count. I can't find any reference to bind the timestamped data to hours and return that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a helper like:

```js
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  foodsByHour: function() {
    var foods = Foods.find().fetch();
    return _.chain(foods)
      .groupBy(function(food) {
        if (food.createdAt)
          return food.createdAt.getHours();
      })
      .map(function(v, k) {return {hour: k, foods: v};})
      .value();
  }
});
```

Which will return an array of `hour` and `foods` pairs like this:

```js
[ { hour: '16',
    foods: 
     [ { text: 'beef',
         createdBy: 'X9Px6qKRjiB53ANST',
         createdAt: Mon Feb 02 2015 16:47:21 GMT-0800 (PST),
         _id: 'sJhwcLCRS4CG6yfTe' },
       { text: 'beef',
         createdBy: 'X9Px6qKRjiB53ANST',
         createdAt: Mon Feb 02 2015 16:47:41 GMT-0800 (PST),
         _id: 'NGBwiWZRsDBbNerSy' } ] },
  { hour: '18',
    foods: 
     [ { text: 'Chicken',
         createdBy: 'X9Px6qKRjiB53ANST',
         createdAt: Mon Feb 02 2015 18:47:21 GMT-0800 (PST),
         _id: 'R2FYAjZamTWTy9RTW' } ] },
  { hour: '20',
    foods: 
     [ { text: 'Chicken',
         createdBy: 'X9Px6qKRjiB53ANST',
         createdAt: Mon Feb 02 2015 20:42:02 GMT-0800 (PST),
         _id: 'F7u2EfBEmYLBaFgze' } ] } ]
```

Here's an example template:

```html
<template name='myTemplate'>
  {{#each foodsByHour}}
    <h2>{{hour}}</h2>
    {{#each foods}}
      <p>{{text}}</p>
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think this is on the right track, I'm getting the following error; `Cannot read property 'getHours' of undefined`

Comment: It seems like that could only happen if you have foods which do not have a `createdAt` property, which is likely a bug outside the scope of this answer. To compensate for this I updated the answer to check for the existence of `createdAt` when grouping the foods. With the above code, you will have an object in your array with an `undefined` hour - you can deal with that however you like in your template.

Comment: Oh of course! There were earlier documents in the collection that hadn't been date stamped. I did a quick `meteor reset` and the original code worked.